# how to create Windows form in VB 10 Express

Tags: vb.net, winforms

This sounds like a dumb question, but I'm using VS 2010 Express edition and cannot find where to add a new Windows form. The templates provided don't indicate a Windows form . Are they called something different in this version of VS?

Comment: Hmm maybe you are using Web-Express? Forms are not included in that version...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I am not sure because I am using the same thing and I just go to the top and click 
**Project>Add Windows Form**